# django Integrity Error

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have an unusual case. In my models.py, I have an Event element, and two different types of user elements that refer to it as seen below.

```
class User(models.Model):

     attending = models.ManyToManyField('Event', related_name='User_attending')
     hosting = models.ForeignKey('Event', related_name='User_hosting')

     username = models.CharField(max_length=40)


class Event(models.Model):
     #event title
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     #time created
     created = models.DateField('Date Created',auto_now_add=True)
```

In my views.py, I when I want to create a user, I have some of the following:

```
    user = User()
    user.username = ""
    user.gender = 0
    user.fName = ""
    user.lName = ""
    ....
    user.save
```

This is when my browser yells at me and says:

Integrity Error,
list_user.hosting_id may not be NULL

Any ideas for a way around this without creating an Event element right there?

Comment: On a related note, your `related_name`s look ugly in python: they should be all lower case. Considering their meaning, I would also pluralize them (users_attending) or use django convention (user_attending_set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want to create a `User` without giving `hosting` a value. You can do this by adding `blank=True, null=True` to the field:

```
hosting = models.ForeignKey('Event', related_name='User_hosting',
                            blank=True, null=True)
```

You'll also need to add a migration to fix the database (as the ability to have an empty field needs to be allowed by the database). I suggest using [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) for this purpose.

Comment: Just wanted to post a comment here, as this Integrity Error can also arise in a situation where it appears that you have provided the required field, but you still get an Integrity Error complaining that it can't be null.  I eventually traced the problem to my serializer, where I had neglected to mention the field.  So check the Serializer if the above answer is not quite what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You've goofed on your relations; they should be on `Event`, pointing to `User`.

Comment: I think they are right as they are... A user can host or attend several events; an event will have users_hosting it or users_attending it...